# PHP: access child property from parent class

Tags: php-5.3

I have this code:

```
abstract class A {
    public function getName()
    {
        return ???;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static $name= 'my name';
}
```

what should I have to put in getName to use the class in this way?

```
$foo = A::getInstance('bla bla');
echo $foo->name;
```

I already implemented the static getInstance and I can see the correct value in $name using xdebug.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok I just realised, in child class

```
const NAME= 'my name';
```

and in getName()

```
return static::NAME;
```